# Professional way to send images from server to client

Tags: database, image, flutter, api, asp.net-core

We are planning our final school project and I need to find out a way to send images from server to client (Flutter App). Due to a lack of experience in a professional environment, I'm struggling to do so.

I've always saved the image name or image path in the database in my smaller projects, got the data via an API, and then just called for the image, which was located on a web server, via HTTP or HTTPS. Pretty easy in Flutter with Image.Network.

However, that doesn't sound like the best option

We are planning on using:

- Ubuntu or Microsoft Server (still to decide)
- MariaDB alone or with MongoDB, or even MS SQL Server(still to decide)
- ASP.NET Core for the API
- Flutter App and Web-Interface for client-side

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing correctly in your smaller projects. This is a best way to do. When frontend(mobile app or web app) uploads image using an API, backend(in your case ASP.NET Core) simply stores that in server(in your case case Ubuntu or Microsoft Server). But I would say stores all media files like audio, video, images, documents, etc on [AWS S3 bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) because it would be difficult to you increase server disk space if its low where AWS-S3 can store any amount of data.

And after saving that media files on S3 or server store its file url in database. Send this url via API to client when it requests it and from client side you just need to use that url to show or download.